# Adding text to the end of string in C

Tags: c

I want to add text to the end of a string. Any ideas why my code down below won't work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char text[20];
    int i;

    printf("Enter a  text\n");
    scanf("%s", &text);

    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
        printf("%c", text[i]);
        if (text[i] == '\0') { //There seems to be something wrong with '\0'
            printf("This is the end of this string");
        }
    }   
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Use [strcat()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) - or strncat() - to append to the end of a string.  Remember: `for i=0; i < strlen(text); i++)` takes you to *ONE ELEMENT **BEFORE** THE DELiMETER*.  ALSO: make sure you have enough room (ie. that the total string is 19 characters or less).

Comment: `if (text[i] == '\0')` this never become true. Also need `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Don't use strcat().  Use strncat().  strcat() is not safe from buffer overflow, whereas strncat() is.  Note that strncat() needs at least `strlen(dest)+n+1` bytes in the `dest` buffer, where `n` is the max number of bytes to append.

Comment: _"my code won't work" "there seems to be something wrong"_ These are not useful problem statements. How is this question supposed to help anyone else in the future?? This website is not your personal free debugging service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two issues:

- `scanf("%s", &text);` should be `scanf("%19s", text);` as `text` is already the address of the character array. The `19` is there to make sure the input is fit into the `text` buffer, leaving at least one space for the `\0` character.
- As you are using `strlen`, you need proper header `<string.h>`

And as BLUEPIXY pointed out `if (text[i] == '\0')` is never TRUE because `strlen` does not include the `\0` character.

Comment: The null character is spelled in lower case, you can also write `'\0'`.  The `NULL` constant is a pointer, also called the null pointer.